# Link Aggration or Bridging (or both)

Tags: networking

I have a PC and a Server both connected to a Switch with 4 NICs each.
Both systems run on SSD and a lots of RAM and i am looking for the fastest way to communicate. The PC runs windows 10, the server Debian x64 (Ubuntu Server).

I was wondering what is faster:

- Use bridging on both PC and Server (create bridge with 4 nics)
- ...or
- Use Link Aggregation on the Switch (2x 4Ports together)
- ...or
- do both, bridge on server and pc AND enable link aggregation

What do you recommend?

Additional Question: What is the recommended way: I normally mount SMB with Windows and AFP/SMB with MacOS. Is there a "faster" protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking directly from one machine to another, link aggregation's performance benefits get conditional. Firstly, there are two types of Link Aggregation: with LACP and without LACP. To gain any performance benefit when talking one machine to one machine, you need to use LACP.

[IEEE 802.3ad or 802.1AX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) Link Aggregation without LACP has a really mischievous gotcha with its link choosing / load balancing algorithm: By default it uses MAC addresses to choose which link to use. With just two machines, you will only get the bandwidth of one link. If you cannot use LACP, you need to investigate if you can change the load balancing algorithm, otherwise there is no performance gain. Link aggregation without LACP makes more sense when one server is communicating to many clients or you are creating a backbone between two networks.

[LACP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation#Link_Aggregation_Control_Protocol) (Link Aggregation Control Protocol) requires your switch and your device to both be configured to use LACP. Once this is done, both side will be able to load balance any traffic round robin across your links. This will get you the performance gains you want.

Bridging, and perhaps I am mixing things up, is not what you want. Putting a software switch in front of all 4 nics on each side of the connection will cause network loops. Bridging won't work.

A quick aside; what many home lab enthusiasts are doing now is buying two 10G or two 40G network cards and using an inexpensive Direct Attach Copper (DAC) cable to link the two machines directly to each other. You might consider this over 4 separate network cards.

Network File System (NFS) is the gold standard for high performance network storage on a shared IP network. NFS has almost line speed bandwidth and very low latency. If you need more performance, Storage Area Network (SAN) or Infiniband are the way to go, but they force you to segregate your IP network from your shared storage/memory network. Samba provides support for more devices than NFS and has acceptable bandwidth. Latency is higher.